# How to convert character in yyyy-mm format to date r

Tags: r, date

I transformed a date in the yyyy-mm-dd format to the yyyy-mm format using the following command:

```
format(as.Date(DATE, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m")
```

This works but it returns a character. I want to further use this as a date, so I want to transform this character back to a date class. Using the as.Date() function gives me the error:

```
Error in charToDate(x) : character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Update: In the end I want to determine the number of months between two dates in the format yyyy-mm. Does anyone knows how to do this without transforming the characters back to date class?

Comment: You should look into `strptime()`

Answer (score -1):

I had once the same problem and unfortunately the only solution I found was to keep format YYYY-mm-dd with dd==01...

Here is part of the code if you want:

```
DATE <- str_c(DATE,"-01") df$date <- as.Date(DATE,format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Comment: Here is part of the code if you want:
DATE <- str_c(DATE,"-01")
df$date <- as.Date(DATE,format="%Y-%m-%d")